# Pass environment variable to qsub jobs

Tags: linux, qsub

I want to add a string to the PATH environment variable of a qsub command. Editing the .sh file is not an option because this is generated and run within the pipeline (I can edit the qsub command options).

**I am running the following qsub command:**

> qsub -pe slots 16 -S /bin/bash -cwd -N "pipeline" -j y -o
>   /home/user/log/out.log /home/user/pipeline/runthis.sh

**I need to add the following PATH environment variable to the shell being run:**

> /home/user/jre1.8.0_66/bin

(this is because the script depends on a more recent version of java than is on the cluster).

**I tried the following:**

> qsub -pe slots 16 -S /bin/bash -cwd -N "pipeline" -j y -o
>   /home/user/log/out.log /home/user/pipeline/runthis.sh -v
>   PATH=/home/pa354/jre1.8.0_66/bin:$PATH -V

This hasn't worked, I added 'env' to the bash file being run (to check the environment variables), my required path has not been added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `-v` in your `qsub` command:

```
qsub -v JAVA_HOME ...
```

This will pass along the environment variable from the calling environment into the spawned job.

Note that the `-v` argument to `qsub` must come before the arguments to the actual command you are running on the remote nodes.  You seem to have tried it at the end of the entire command line which isn't going to work.

Comment: Yep, but how would I add a string to the PATH variable specifically. I have tried the following qsub -V, qsub -v PATH=/.../../bin$PATH, qsub -v PATH=/../../bin$PATH -V. I am running a bash script, the 'env' output does not show any additions to the PATH variable.

Comment: @ParsaAkbari: See my update, you need to reorder the elements of your command line a little bit.

Comment: What does '-v' stand for?

Comment: @vicemagui see `man qsub`: `-v var[=value] will specifically pass environment variable ‘var’ to the job`.  So it passes JAVA_HOME through to the job.